# Using a Graph Database in my Java mobile app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm working on a mobile app that requires data treatement using graphs in my database, and looking for that i found neo4j and other technologies that may be useful in my case, but the problem it lies here: i'm not working with Maven like most documentations say and tutorials show, i'm using here gradle and i'm trying to implement a sort f a graph database but nothing i looked so much and i ionly found that they work wheter with srpingboot or a Maven build system, isn't there any technology that can i sue to implement a graph database using pure Java and with Gradle ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It might be helpful for you to understand what Maven and Gradle are what their job is.  Both Maven and Gradle do the same job, that is they can build and package your project, the only difference is that they have a different approach to that, but in general both will download JAR's from a source repository.  It is quite easy to have your Gradle project pull in a JAR from Maven central or other Maven repository, the Maven GAV coordinate is the same it is just written differently.

Comment: Having a quick look at the Neo4J developer docs shows how to import the library JAR using both Maven and Gradle

Comment: I took a deeper look into neo4j doc and i found some denied google permissions when trying to connect my app with the neo4j db while building my project